# The application sometimes restarts multiple times after shutdown

Tags: android

I have a problem, users report that when the application shuts down (ending the process), the app restarts and user must shuts it down again and the app restarts again. Sometimes even 4x ...

How is it possible? I will close all the services & activities that have been started and I will terminate the whole process ...

I've noticed that only users with android 7 report it to me. It's never happened to me (android 5).

It is the same restart as if the activity is an error, just an exception and a restart. But Fabric.io tool has no record of any errors ... so I do not know what could happen, does anyone have any idea?

Comment: When you say that the app restarts - does it open an activity by itself? Maybe there is a service running in the background that keeps the process alive or invoke an intent to an activity?

Answer (score 0):

Add a Log.d statement into your onCreate in the Application class.

Extent the application class

```
public class TheApplication extends Application {
 @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d("restart", "My App is restarting");
}
```

}

and in the manifest

```
    android:name=".TheApplication" <-- make sure the package is correct.
```

Install the app adb install yourapp.apk

open a terminal

adb logcat restart *:S

then click on your app and watch the terminal.

This way you don't have to run it in debug mode and it runs like a regular app.

If you see it logging the app restarting several times maybe you can put in a trace in places (loging) like put one in the onDestroy of the main launcher class.

hope you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

It could happen from the 3rd party library that you includes into the project.

Some of them might have a service to trigger something intervally and that  wake up the app the couple times.

This issue happened before on the app that i've been working on where the app keep waking up after that particular library get included.

Please check for any service that running in the background.